# Windows 7 has two recycle bins

Tags: windows-7, windows

One is empty and one is full. I cannot figure out how to get to the full recycle bin to delete it.  I can see both recycle bins but can only access one.  It has to be a sub folder of some kind.  I am not very great with computer issues like this and can use all the help I can get.  I tried to open the files and rt click to delete but it will not allow me to do either of these things.

Comment: Could you please show screenshots?

Comment: Could be one bin for user A, another bin for user B. Normally, each user only has rights to their own bin unless they've got Admin rights.

Comment: @Christina McKaughan  imgur.com and other sources are useful to share screenshots when you're new here and don't have enough points to directly upload. Post a screenshot through a site like Imgur, then add the URL linking to the screenshot, by clicking on `edit` above and at left, to add the update into your original post.

Comment: Do you have multiple drives?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see if it helps.

1. On windows 7, click `win` key,
2. Search `show or hide common icons on the desktop`
3. Uncheck the Recycle Bin, and apply to see if the two recycle bin will disappear.
4. And re-check the `Recycle Bin`.

Or try to `Restore Default` to see if it helps.

[image]